# Is the package wosr still usable?

Tags: r, bibliography

I am making a literature review using Web of Science queries. I wanted to use the [wosr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wosr/index.html) package to make the queries directly in R but I keep having error messages. I think it is related to the maintenance of the package.

For instance, I used the example given by the package itself:

```
library(wosr)
sid <- auth(username = NULL, password = NULL)
pull_wos("TS = (dog welfare) AND PY = 2010", sid = sid)
```

And it returns:

```
Error: (IIE0022) The SOAP request message is invalid. Reason: Error received from a server supporting the Web service. Cause: The following input is invalid [Not authorized to edition BHCI in collection WOS]. Remedy: Correct your request and submit it again.
```

Does anyone here knows if the package is still operational? Did someone already used this package? Is there an other alternative to make queries on WoS directly in R?

Comment: Did you replace the `NULL` values with your own username and password?

Comment: Well, I tried to use some of my credentials but I am not really sure which one to use. I am using WoS through my univ credentials but it was telling me that no account were linked to the username used.

Comment: You probably need API credentials which are different from general user credentials. If you click "log in" [on this page](https://developer.clarivate.com/apis/wos) there seems to be a place to create an account.